# How to call Square API method asynchronously

Tags: angularjs, square-connect, square

### How to call paymentForm.requestCardNonce() method asynchronous

I am integrating square payment gateway in AngularJs, Now I have situation where I have to call `paymentForm.requestCardNonce()` and this method calls web service in background. Now I have to wait for background call than I can proceed with furthered process. So how can i handle callback from `paymentForm.requestCardNonce()` method which is provided by Square Payment Gateway https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/sqpaymentform/setup

**Initialising code sample**

```
var paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({
    applicationId: "sandbox-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    inputClass: 'sq-input',
    callbacks: {
        cardNonceResponseReceived: function (errors, nonce, cardData, billingContact, shippingContact) {
        // I am receiving response of web service Here
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get success response in my custom function by calling method in it ?(Note - its working and calling a method also but i have to do next steps based on response from web service)

```
addCard = function () {
   paymentForm.requestCardNonce();
   // Till this function executes I need to wait here. how can I write promise here ?
}
```

**Refrence LInks**
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/sqpaymentform/how-it-works

https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/tree/master/templates/web-ui/payment-form/basic

Comment: Do you mind explaining what you’re trying to do? `requestCardNonce` is asynchronous, and when it completes it will call `cardNonceResponseReceived`, so if you’re wanting to call a function after it’s finished, you should place it in `cardNonceResponseReceived`.

Comment: hi @sjosey, As you explained I have implemented and it works! I have added next execution code to another function and called in `cardNonceResponseReceived`. Thanks

Comment: Anyone know, Is possible with real-time inventory sync with square and Magento 1.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity, pulling from the comments.

`requestCardNonce` is asynchronous, and when it completes it will call `cardNonceResponseReceived`, so if you’re wanting to call a function after it’s finished, you should place it in `cardNonceResponseReceived`.